# sklearn pipeline - Applying sample weights after applying a polynomial feature transformation in a pipeline

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, pipeline

I want to apply sample weights and at the same time use a pipeline from sklearn which should make a feature transformation, e.g. polynomial, and then apply a regressor, e.g. ExtraTrees.

I am using the following packages in the two examples below:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
```

Everything works well as long as I seperately transform the features and generate and train the model afterwards:

```
#Feature generation
X = np.random.rand(200,4)
Y = np.random.rand(200)

#Feature transformation
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
poly.fit_transform(X)

#Model generation and fit
clf = ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators=5, max_depth = 3)
weights = [1]*100 + [2]*100
clf.fit(X,Y, weights)
```

But doing it in a pipeline, does not work:

```
#Pipeline generation
pipe = Pipeline([('poly2', PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)), ('ExtraTrees', ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators=5, max_depth = 3))])

#Feature generation
X = np.random.rand(200,4)
Y = np.random.rand(200)

#Fitting model
clf = pipe
weights = [1]*100 + [2]*100
clf.fit(X,Y, weights)
```

I get the following error: TypeError: fit() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
In this simple example, it is no issue to modify the code, but when I want to run several different tests on my real data in my real code, being able to use pipelines and sample weight

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is mention of `**fit_params` in the `fit` method of [`Pipeline`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) documentation.  You must specify which step of the pipeline you want to apply the parameter to.  You can achieve this by following the naming rules in the docs:

> For this, it enables setting parameters of the various steps using their names and the parameter name separated by a ‘__’, as in the example below.

So all that being said, try changing the last line to:

```
clf.fit(X,Y, **{'ExtraTrees__sample_weight': weights})
```

**Updated link**: [This is a good example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-grid-search-text-feature-extraction-py) of how to work with parameters in pipelines.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin! This solved the problem and the example is really nice to see how parameters work in pipelines!

Comment: "This is a good example of how to work with parameters in pipelines." This link is dead.