# XGboost python - classifier class weight option?

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost

Is there a way to set different class weights for xgboost classifier? For example in sklearn RandomForestClassifier this is done by the "class_weight" parameter.

Comment: NOTE: All of the solutions below no longer work as sample_weight is not supported anymore.

Comment: scale_pos_weight is the right parameter. Look at my answer below.

Comment: @SriK yep, but it only works for binary classification problems

Comment: @SriK I am not quite a STAFF/Senior in machine learning, but based on what I see in the scikit-learn version of XGBoost, we do have sample-weight available, and it just worked fantastically well for my research on rare diseases a few minutes ago. https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn

Answer (score 12, accepted):

when using the sklearn wrapper, there is a parameter for weight.

example:

```
import xgboost as xgb
exgb_classifier = xgboost.XGBClassifier()
exgb_classifier.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weights_data)
```

where the parameter shld be array like, length N, equal to the target length

Comment: How can you use it with **Pipeline**? As you can't use `fit` directly inside a pipeline

Comment: @Deshwal As this is a different type of inquiry and I would not like to delve into a response that is unrelated to the original, here's a decent article discussing such a thing: https://towardsdatascience.com/pipelines-custom-transformers-in-scikit-learn-the-step-by-step-guide-with-python-code-4a7d9b068156

Answer (score 18):

**For sklearn version < 0.19**

Just assign each entry of your train data its class weight. First get the class weights with `class_weight.compute_class_weight` of sklearn then assign each row of the train data its appropriate weight.

I assume here that the train data has the column `class` containing the class number. I assumed also that there are `nb_classes` that are from 1 to `nb_classes`.

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
classes_weights = list(class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                             np.unique(train_df['class']),
                                             train_df['class']))

weights = np.ones(y_train.shape[0], dtype = 'float')
for i, val in enumerate(y_train):
    weights[i] = classes_weights[val-1]

xgb_classifier.fit(X, y, sample_weight=weights)
```

**Update for sklearn version >= 0.19**

There is simpler solution

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
classes_weights = class_weight.compute_sample_weight(
    class_weight='balanced',
    y=train_df['class']
)

xgb_classifier.fit(X, y, sample_weight=classes_weights)
```

Comment: I get your answer and it works fine but how can you do this when you have to use **Pipeline**? You can't use the `fit` method directly.

Comment: @Deshwal As this is a different type of inquiry and I would not like to delve into a response that is unrelated to the original, here's a decent article discussing such a thing: https://towardsdatascience.com/pipelines-custom-transformers-in-scikit-learn-the-step-by-step-guide-with-python-code-4a7d9b068156

Comment: For using `sample_weight` with `Pipeline`, there is an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36224909/407108

Answer (score 7):

I recently ran into this problem, so thought will leave a solution I tried

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

# manually handling imbalance. Below is same as computing float(18501)/392318 
on the trainig dataset.
# We are going to inversely assign the weights
weight_ratio = float(len(y_train[y_train == 0]))/float(len(y_train[y_train == 
1]))
w_array = np.array([1]*y_train.shape[0])
w_array[y_train==1] = weight_ratio
w_array[y_train==0] = 1- weight_ratio

xgc = XGBClassifier()
xgc.fit(x_df_i_p_filtered, y_train, sample_weight=w_array)
```

Not sure, why but the results were pretty disappointing. Hope this helps someone.

[Reference link] https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/99824/xgboost.XGBClassifier

Comment: Should be w1 = np.array([1.0] * y_train.shape[0]) , initializing the numpy array's dtype as a float. Otherwise the following statements will result in a numpy array containing all zeros.

Answer (score 3):

```
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_sample_weight
xgb_classifier.fit(X, y, sample_weight=compute_sample_weight("balanced", y))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer before getting to the code implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The answers here are outdated. THe sample_weight parameter is no longer supported. Its replaced with scale_pos_weight

Rather just do scale_pos_weight  = sum(negative instances) / sum(positive instances)

Comment: yep, but this only works for binary classification problems

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use the `scale_pos_weight` hyperparameter, as discussed in the [XGBoost docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html). The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to construct the sample weight vector, and don't have to pass in the sample weight vector at `fit` time.

Comment: interesting. I tried with my problem and my question is how different is this method from sample_weight in the fit method? if you have an insight about this, it would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Firas Omrane and @Pramit answer, but I think it is slightly more pythonic

```py
    from sklearn.utils import class_weight
    class_weights = dict(
            zip(
                [0,1],
                class_weight.compute_class_weight(
                    'balanced', classes=np.unique(train['class']), y=train['class']
                ),
            )
        ) 
    
    xgb_classifier.fit(X, train['class'], sample_weight=class_weights)
```

Comment: The format of this `class_weights` is not the expected by `xgb`. Could you elaborate if there is anything extra that needs to be done to make it work? Thanks

Comment: @juanbretti Using Skibee's response will not work with Scikit-xgboost learn's implementation since they require a list similar to your class target (i.e., the same size) but with the weight value for this i th instead of 1, 0 or whatever the unique values in your column are. Thus, this answer is ideal for logging, for example, what class weights should be applied to your unique values. However, I would recommend using class weight.compute sample weight when using it with XGBoost Scikit Learn implementation. Do you understand? or still confused?